# Invalid client secret provided - Azure Databricks, API Auth

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, databricks, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to authorize my application to query Log Analytics API. As part of the process described in the Microsoft documentation, I need to request a token using the Microsoft Entra ID OAuth2 flow.

I can't find the mistake, since I'm using a scope inside databricks to access the secret inside a keyvault.
The value of the secret belongs to a Service Principal.

I'm running a jupyter notebook inside databricks. Here's the code (anonimized):

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx/oauth2/token"
 
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
 
key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="kv_XXX", key="XXXx")
 
payload = {"grant_type":"client_credentials",
           "client_id": "2xxxxx",  
           "scope":"34xxxxxxx/.default", 
           "client_secret": key} 
 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
 
print(response.text)
```

Here's the error:

> AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app 'xxxxx'.

I've tried other authentication methods, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You might be providing the secret ID instead of the secret value.

You need to add the secret value as highlighted in the image below to your Key Vault secrets.

[image]

So, verify the value you've entered in the Key Vault secrets to ensure it's correct.

```py
import requests
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token"
 
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
 
key = dbutils.secrets.get('tst_scope','cogsec')
 
payload = {"grant_type":"client_credentials",
           "client_id": "<client_id>",  
           "scope":"<client_id>/.default", 
           "client_secret": key} 
 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
 
print(response.text)
```

Output:

[image]

If you are still getting the error, check whether you are passing the secret value of the correct application to which you have given permission.